# Reverse Square Bracket and it's Denotation (Notation)

Tags: notation

Some one asked me to use reverse square bracket instead of parenthesis (.,.) to denote open interval, and I have confused with meaning of reverse square bracket and the notation (denotation) of it. So, can I get your help to know the meaning of reverse square bracket, and how we denote it?

Comment: Do you mean $]\cdot,\cdot[$? Then $]a,b[ = (a,b)$, where the right hand side is your usual notation for an open interval. Similarly, $[a,b[ = [a,b)$, and so on. Personally I think it’s a nice way to avoid ambiguity about whether $(x,y)$ means the pair of objects consisting of $x$ and $y$, or the open interval contained between $x$ and $y$, but it is unfortunately not as commonly used as I’d like. ($\LaTeX$ doesn’t also seem to kern it properly.)

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist `\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[` Also `\mathrm{\LaTeX}` to get $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ in MathJax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My question is "what does  reverse square bracket  mean."  Because, some journals ask to use reverse square bracket to denote the open interval (a,b), and I have confused with the meaning of reverse square bracket.